# Definition Query to exclude multiple values from multiple fields

Tags: definition-query

I have tried multiple iterations, but nothing seems to work. Here are two of my latest attempts:

```
NOT NPDES_NUM1 = 'IL0066265' OR NOT RCRA_ID_1 = 'IL1410175005' OR NOT RCRA_ID_1 = 'ILD006935571
```

This also did not work:

```
"NPDES_NUM1" NOT IN (IL0066265) OR "RCRA_ID_1" NOT IN (IL1410175005, ILD006935571)
```

(nothing selected, I also tried to replace "OR" with "AND"...still null

Update: I am using ArcMap 10.5.1

Comment: You have a fundamental issue with Boolean logic and Set Theory here, in addition to probable formatting issues.  `OR` and `NOT` are extremely powerful operators alone and when used in conjunction, without parenthesis, are likely to cause problems.  When working a logic problem, it's usually helpful to construct a truth table, but I fear this is at the edge of being off-topic (not GIS-centric enough).

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

As your value are text value you should use single quote :

> "NPDES_NUM1" NOT IN ('IL0066265') OR "RCRA_ID_1" NOT IN
> ('IL1410175005', 'ILD006935571')

This will exclude recors that match one OR the other condition (or both condition as the same time) . If you want to exclude record only when both condition are respected you should use the AND operator.